# Can I use Capistrano from a windows dev setup to deploy to a Linux server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Can I use Capistrano from a windows dev machine to deploy to a Linux server?  This is for a rails app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**: Yes you can.

I think you can, capistrano is a gem, so should install on windows machine too. Yes, this is definitely possible, I did too a long time ago. Should work similar as on linux or mac osx.

Comment: More vague than that, just two of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can, I'm doing it now.

However I've found one issue - that it's difficult or impossible to set up SSH using a stored key, meaning that you have to type your SSH password into the deployment script manually (or store the password in your Capistrano script - as this gets uploaded to your server, don't do this!). I can't remember exactly what the issue is, but if I remember right, the guy who maintains Capistrano doesn't use Windows and isn't interested in investigating the issue.

When I get some time, I'm intending to get Capistrano running from within Cygwin - I already have password-less SSH to my hosting server working within Cygwin, and I believe Capistrano running from within there should just work.

Answer (score 0):

Capistrano don't use some system command where you launch the capistrano command. So it's completly OS-agnostic